# Loading windows 2000 on IBM Server x3650

Tags: windows, ibm

We need to load IBM server x3650 with Windows server 2000, this is required to support a legacy software.

How do we do this, Please advise.

Comment: I would install ESXi and run Windows 2000 as a VM.

Comment: Asking "can I" vs. "how do I" is a huge difference.  "How do I" is more of a __book answer__ , even more so if you go the ESXi route (properly).  If you aren't sure how to load up an x3650 (m1/2/3?) using ServerGuide, etc. then you'll need to research that out or hire a pro.

Comment: As a professional, you should refuse to do this because it's *wrong*. Server 2000 is long dead and unsupported, and you will get blamed when it blows up. To top it off, there are myriad application virtualization solutions out there, in addition to server virtualization.

Comment: @jscott: can you please guide me more on this. I'm new to VM's Or please point me to some links

Comment: @user75464 You can download [VMware ESXi/vSphere from here](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html). There are myriad documents describing how to build/configure a VM, I'd start with documents from the VMware site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Download ESXi from [here](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html)
2. Read VMware's [guides on how to configure it](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-installation-setup-guide.pdf).
3. Install Windows 2000 as a VM.
4. ????
5. Profit.